# Microsoft Azure Website the service ins unavailable

Tags: azure, web

Suddenly, none of my 4 azure websites are available. They worked 10min ago and now nothing. On my portal, no error messages or quotas exceeded etc. On the azure service Dashboard, no problem is reported. Of course you don't know how to reach any kind of Customer support.

Any help is very welcome :-)

François

Comment: It is now back. However, I would still like to understand what I could do to avoid this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Azure under maintenance. They posted this yesterday on their portal.